# Reference request for a modification of Bi-Intuitionistic Logic

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, modal-logic, intuitionism

I’ve asked this same question [on math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4788089/28111), but haven’t received any answers. I ask this question in good faith, so I hope it meets this site’s standards.

I have been spending the better part of a year thinking about the subtleties involved in balancing natural language intuitions for logic with the power and efficacy that Classical Logic and Intuitionsitic Logic provide. In so doing, I believe that I’ve discovered/invented a logic that is very similar to Bi-Intuitionistic Logic. The operators are defined the same way they usually are for a Kripke semantics for Intuitionistic Logic except that

$w \Vdash \neg A$ iff there is a $v$ s.t. $w \le v$ and $v \not \Vdash A$ where $\le$ is the accessibility relation between states.

For reference, the semantics for Bi-Intuitionistic Logic defines its weak negation $\sim$ as

$w \Vdash \sim A$ iff there is a $v$ s.t. $v \le w$ and $v \not \Vdash A$.

Below is an axiomatization for the altered semantics. Note that strong negation, $\top$, and $\bot$ may be defined in terms of $\neg$ and $\to$.

A1. $(B→C)→A→B→C$

A2. $(A→B)→(A→(B→C)) \to A→C$

B1. $(A→B)→¬B→¬A$

B2. $\neg (A \to A) \to C$

B3. $\neg(A \to B) \to ¬B$

B4. $(\neg(A→B)→B)→A→B$

$\lor$I. $A_i \to (A_1 \lor A_2)$ $\   $ where $i=1$ or $i=2$

$\land$E. $(A_1 \land A_2) \to A_i$ $\   $ where $i=1$ or $i=2$

$\land$I. $(A \to B) \to (A \to C) \to A \to (B \land C)$

$\lor$E$. ((A \land B) \to D) \to ((A \land C) \to D) \to (A \land (B \lor C)) \to D$

MP$:$ From $\vdash A$ and $\vdash A \to B$ infer $\vdash B$

NI$:$ From $\Gamma \vdash A$ infer $\Gamma \vdash A’$ where $A’$ results from the substitution $[(\top \to B)/B]$ for any Condition 1 formula $B$ occurring in $A$.

Condition 1 is defined for wffs $A$ as follows:

- If $A$ is a positive literal, then $A$ is Condition 1.
- If $A=(B \to C)$, then $A$ is Condition 1
- If $A=(B \land C)$ or $A=(B \lor C)$, and both $B$ and $C$ are Condition 1, then $A$ is as well.
- All and only Condition 1 formulas are constructed with finitely-many applications of these rules.

If NI is removed, the resulting logic is the same except that formulas built from only positive literals do not retain the Heredity Condition of Intuitionistic logic.

I know that there is a lot of recent research in this area of logic, but I haven’t been able to find any works by professional logicians on it. I am curious since this logic shares many similarities with both Relevance Logics, Intuitionistic Logic, and Classical Logic. Specifically, the implication in this logic is still the Intuitionistic implication, i.e.

$w\Vdash (A \to B)$ iff for any $v$ s.t. $wRv$, if  $v \Vdash A$ then $v \Vdash B$.

But, the weak negation simultaneously validates semi-classical results like $(\neg A \to A) \to A$ and invalidates much of positive implicational logic, e.g. $A \to B \to A$.

Further, the full logic including the rule NI validates these analogues to some lesser-known modal logic axioms

$((A \to (\top \to A)) \to A) \to A$ [Grz. Axiom]

$- -A \to \neg \neg A$ [Mckinsey Axiom]

where $-$ is strong negation. These hold for the entire propositional portion of the logic and much of the first order portion.

When $\bot$ is defined, the pair of axiom schemata

$\neg (A \to B) \to \neg B$

$(\neg (A \to B) \to B) \to A \to B$

may be replaced by the axiom schema

$((A \to B’) \to (A \to C)) \to (A \to (\neg B \to C)) \to A \to C$

where $B’=B$ or $B’=\neg B \to \bot$.

Though unconventional, it is most natural to define $\bot:=\neg(A \to A)$ and $\top:=(\bot \to \bot)$.

Comment: Please write down explicitly what you think $\bot$ and $\top$ are.  Once you do, please argue that $\top \to B$ and $B$ are not equivalent, lest NI be vacuous. You say that your semnatics of implication is the standard one for Kripke models. Doesn't your semantics therefore validate $A \to B \to A$? Given your claims, it would help if you spell out the semantic clauses for the operators.

Comment: @AndrejBauer The validity of $A\to(B\to A)$ does not follow from the standard semantics of $\to$. It also relies on upwards persistence of $A$, which is here violated by formulas involving $\neg$. Cf. axiom A1. Likewise, $\top\to B$ is different from $B$ if $B$ is not persistent.

Comment: One thing that is unclear to me is whether propositional *atoms* are assumed to be persistent.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek By “positive literal” I include propositional atoms. Substitution is preserved for non-persistent formulas given that the rule NI is not used for them.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I added definitions.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek apparently you understand better than I do what the OP is presenting here. I would appreciate more details, for instance what "standard semantics" is supposed to mean. Given what the OP stated, I would presume we are talking about [Kripke structures](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/#KripBethSemaForIntuLogi), and for those $A \to (B \to A)$ is valid (because intuitionistic propostional calculus is sound for them). It would be best to sort out things by having more precise definitions, as they are claimed to be non-standard somehow.

Comment: Do not mark things as "Edit 1", this is not reddit. Just make your question self-contained, please. It would make sense to put semantics up front. I don't see the definition of $\Vdash$ anywhere, please provide a reference or spell it out. Is it [this definition](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/#KripBethSemaForIntuLogi)?

Comment: So $w\Vdash(A\lor\neg A)$ for any $w$ and $A$?

Comment: Also it seems that whenever $w\Vdash(A\to\bot)$ then also $w\Vdash\neg A$

Comment: Actually you might have modal translation somewhere above S4, with $\operatorname{tr}(p)=\Box p$, $\operatorname{tr}(A\to B)=\Box(\operatorname{tr}(A)\to\operatorname{tr}(B))$, and $\operatorname{tr}(\neg A)=\Diamond(\neg\operatorname{tr}(A))$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე yes that’s correct.

Comment: Then you should be able to capture the whole modal logic except classical negation, through$$\Diamond(A)=\neg(A\to\bot)$$given that$$\Box(A)=(\top\to A)=(\neg A)\to\bot$$

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე Yes, the modal translation was one of the things that inspired/facilitated my work with this logic.